# WCF Connection Reset

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm creating a WCF Service, and it's working fine while I'm connecting it to a WinForms Client. But I want to access it throught the browser. Some methods are working fine, but when I'm trying to send back an object that includes multiples objects it returns the error message "A connection was reset"... I was trying to test my service with ARC and with JQuery Ajax, and all the cases I received the same error.

I almost forgot telling you, this issue only happens if I create a instance to Period attribute. If I return the object clear, I don't have any issue.

I share to you a test I made based on the original code. I hope you could help me.

WCF Service

```
using MercSoft.Conservatorio.DataModels;
using MercSoft.Conservatorio.Request;
using MercSoft.Conservatorio.Response;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace Mercsoft.Conserv.WSv2
{
     [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
     [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
     public class Conservatorio
     {
          // To use HTTP GET, add [WebGet] attribute. (Default ResponseFormat is WebMessageFormat.Json)
         // To create an operation that returns XML,
         //     add [WebGet(ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml)],
         //     and include the following line in the operation body:
         //         WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/xml";
         [OperationContract]
         public void DoWork()
         {
              // Add your operation implementation here
              return;
         }

         [OperationContract(Name = "EstaActivo"), WebGet]
         public bool isActive()
         {
              return false;
         }

         [OperationContract(Name="PruebaOro"), WebInvoke(Method="POST", ResponseFormat= WebMessageFormat.Json)]
         public PreRegisterResponse pruebaOro(PreRegisterRequest request)
         {
              PreRegisterResponse response = new PreRegisterResponse();
              response.Period = new ModulesDataModel();
              return response;
         }
         // Add more operations here and mark them with [OperationContract]
     }
}
```

PreRegister Response

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using MercSoft.Conservatorio.DataModels;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using MercSoft.Conservatorio.Request;

namespace MercSoft.Conservatorio.Response
{
     [DataContract]
     public class PreRegisterResponse : BaseResponse
     {
          [DataMember]
          public PreRegisterDataModel Period { get; set; }

          public PreRegisterResponse()
              : base()
          {
          }
     }
}
```

PreRegisterDataModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;

namespace MercSoft.Conservatorio.DataModels
{
    [DataContract(IsReference=true)]
    public class SystemPeriodsDataModel
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int PeriodType { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public String PeriodTypeString { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public String DatePeriod { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public bool WithInstument { get; set; } //Pre-register ONLY
        [DataMember]
        public bool Active { get; set; }
    }
}
```

WebConfig

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <configuration>

          <appSettings>
            <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
          </appSettings>
          <system.web>
            <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
            <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
          </system.web>
          <system.serviceModel>
            <services>
              <service name="Mercsoft.Conserv.WSv2.Conservatorio">
                <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="Mercsoft.Conserv.WSv2.ConservatorioAspNetAjaxBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Mercsoft.Conserv.WSv2.Conservatorio" />
              </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="Mercsoft.Conserv.WSv2.ConservatorioAspNetAjaxBehavior">
              <enableWebScript />
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="">
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <protocolMapping>
            <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
        </protocolMapping>    
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
      </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found the same issue with a piece of code in a WCF service I'm working on, that is (now) using the webHttpBinding (for REST clients). The culprit was the property "IsReference=true" in a DataContract class. I needed that flag set to TRUE because the graph of objects contains circular references; this way the returned response has a lot less bytes than if the real objects were serialized.

I don't know why this works with SOAP and other bindings but not with webHttpBinding, but since I needed to add REST support, the service stopped working when a DataContract class with IsReference=true was being returned.

My temporary solution was to create another class with the same properties as the original, but without the IsReference property. I need to investigate this further but in the meantime I hope this helps.